# Google Login API

Tags: java, android, authentication

Faced such a problem that the **Google Login API** does not work if you switch to another `Activity`.

I create static class with Google Login. Looks like this:

```
public class GoogleLoginImpl
{
    static String TAG = "GoogleLoginImpl";
    public static GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = null;
    public static GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions = null;
    public static GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = null;

    public static void init(Context context)
    {
        googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .enableAutoManage((FragmentActivity)context, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Connection failed : " + connectionResult.getErrorMessage());
                    }
                })
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, googleSignInOptions)
                .build();

        googleApiClient.connect();
    }
}
```

I call `GoogleLoginImpl.init(getContext())` on  MainAcitivty  in `onCreate()` method. And if i stay on MainActivity all work fine and if i call `GoogleLoginImpl.googleApiClient.isConnected()` it return true, but if i go to another Activity then i get false.

What i can do with that? I want create page with profile info and logout button, but it doesent work.

Comment: you may have to call this method in onResume of activity

Comment: okay, thank you, i do it and it now work fine

Comment: i check it little bit more and find error, after i come back to MainActivity, and now get false